# How to make text selectable swiper js react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js

I'm creating a slider with swiper js and react. the slider is working but the text is not selectable.

probably because of `pointer-events: none` how can I make the content selectable ?

```
<Swiper
  spaceBetween={50}
  slidesPerView={3}
>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the click event acts as a touch event and the slide follows the mouse movement when you hold it. Maybe that's the problem.